# What connects a bird, a childrens’ toy, and a mode of transport?

Tags: riddle, word

I got asked this today and I  don’t know the answer. Will someone please help me figure it out?

Here is the riddle: “What connects a bird, a childrens’ toy, and a mode of transport?”

Answer (score 10):

My answer would have to be

> Superman ... *"It's a bird, it's a plane, it's Superman!"*

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE @dakotadouglas! (Take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven’t already!) That is a great first answer. Can you elaborate a bit more on how it fits the clues? In particular, I’m not sure how that answer fits with “children’s toy”

Answer (score 4):

Going for the Monkey Island Solution:

> A rubber chicken with a pulley inside

1. > it's a chicken (bird)
2. > it's a kids toy (toy)
3. > you can use the pulley on a zip wire (transport)

Comment: Monkey island??

Comment: https://www.mobygames.com/images/promo/original/1469759993-2253442224.jpg

Comment: If anything I have more questions, but fair enough.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Half a billion monkeys with typewriters will produce arbitrary strings of letters one of which will contain a valid answer to this puzzle. Now if you gather the monkeys on an island... wait I've re-checked, if you start with half a billion, you will most likely end up with a few dozens of valid answers.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I figured you'd just have a bunch of starving and/or cannibal monkeys.

Comment: Eventually they mutate into three headed monkeys...

Answer (score 1):

My answer would be:

> Flying/Flight

Reasons Why

1. > Birds can fly
2. > There are lots of types of childrens’ toys that can fly in some way. Some examples are small, remote control helicopters and paper airplanes.
3. > Flying by being in an airplane is a method of transport